# Norm Inequality: Other

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I need help proving this inequality to understand a preliminary remark.

$$\Bigg |\Bigg| \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\|y\|}\Bigg |\Bigg| \geq \|x-y\| $$
with $x$ and $y$ satisying $\|x\|,\|y\|\leq 1$ and $\|x-y\|\geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

If $\ \| x\| \leqslant \| y \| \ $ , we  write:

$\left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\| = \left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| x\|} + \dfrac{y}{\| x\| } - \dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\|$

We use the triangle inequality to obtain:

$\left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\| \geq \left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| x\|}\right\| - \left\| \dfrac{y}{\| x\| } - \dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\|$

Then:

$\left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\| \geq \dfrac{1}{\| x\|} \|x-y\| - \left( \dfrac{1}{\| x\|} -\dfrac{1}{\| y\| }\right) \| y\|$

We know that    $\ \|y\| \leqslant 1 \leqslant \| x-y\| $

So:

$\left\|\dfrac{x}{\| x\|}-\dfrac{y}{\| y\|}\right\| \geq \dfrac{1}{\| x\|} \|x-y\| - \left( \dfrac{1}{\| x\|} -\dfrac{1}{\| y\| }\right) \| x-y\| = \dfrac{\|x-y\|}{\| y\|} \geqslant \|x-y\|$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|y\|\geq \|x\|$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|x\|\|x-y\|&=&\|y\|\|x-y\|-(\|y\|-\|x\|)\|x-y\|\qquad {\rm (trivially)}\\\\
&\leq&\|y\|\|x-y\|-(\|y\|-\|x\|)\|y\|\qquad {\rm (as}\,\,\|y\|\leq1 \leq\|x-y\|)\\\\
&=&{\large\|}\|y\|(x-y){\large\|}-{\large\|}(\|y\|-\|x\|)y{\large\|}\qquad {\rm (by\,\, scalability\,\, of\,\, norm)}\\\\
&\leq&{\large\|}\|y\|x-\|x\|y{\large\|}\qquad {\rm (by\,\, triangle\,\, inequality\,\, }\|A\|-\|B\|\leq\|A+B\|)
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $$\|x-y\|\leq \frac{\|x\|\|x-y\|}{\|x\|\|y\|}\leq \left\| \frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|$$

Comment: The intuitive picture that motivated the above proof is the triangle $\Delta\left(0\frac{x}{\|x\|}\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)$.  The point $\frac{x}{\|y\|}$ lies on one edge of this triangle,  and its distance to the opposite vertex $\frac{y}{\|y\|}$ is greater than or equal to the length of 
 the edge on one side $\left(0\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)$ .  It therefore cannot also be greater than the  length of the edge on the other side  $\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)$.